# Setting error message from one form control to another form control

Tags: angular

this.outPutCtrl and this.optionCtrl are 2 formcontrol

```
   if(this.optionCtrl?.status === 'INVALID') {
```

console.log(this.optionCtrl?.errors) gives {required: true}

I want to set the error from optionCtrl to to outPutCtrl , but when required is coming error message is not setting

```
    this.outPutCtrl.setErrors({ message: this.optionCtrl?.errors?.message })
  }
```

Comment: Can your provide some more code?  This is not enough to understand what the issue is.